# MFP.Server.invokeProcedure not working in Mobilefirst 8

Tags: maven, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am trying to call one of the JS adapter procedure from another JS adapter procedure.It is not calling another JS adapter procedure. I have used below code format:

```
MFP.Server.invokeProcedure({
    adapter : "AdapterName", 
    procedure : "procedureName", 
    parameters : ["MobileFirst"]
});
```

Please let me know if I have to integrate all these adapters into a single Maven project. Or, if it was created as a separate individual project in eclipse then also it will work. Please let me know where is the problem.
 Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the [Data Mashup Sample tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/#data-mashup-example) which includes how to call JavaScript Adapter Procedure from another JavaScript Adapter Scenario.